# I have something like this code and I would like to know how to get the number of elements of the array I pass in, if there is a way

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

So int size does not actually give me the size of what I pass in, in the main function. How do I get the exact number of elements in the array that I pass in.

```
void myFunc(int *array)
{ int size = (sizeof(&array)/sizeof(int));} 

int main()
{
 int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
 myfunc(&array);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You add an argument to the function for the number of elements.

Comment: Also note that in the `main` function, using `&array` gives you something that is of type `int (*)[13]`. Not really the same as the `int *` you want the function to receive. Enable more warnings fromn the compiler if that doesn't already produce a warning. And treat warnings as errors. The good news is that it's simple to fix: Don't use the address-of operator on the array. Using plain `array` will have the array decay to a pointer to the first element (of the correct type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as parameter to myFunc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myFunc(int *array, size_t size)
{
    printf("Size = %zu\n", size);

    for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%zu] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

    myFunc(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

1. `main` signature must be `int main(void)`
2. `sizeof` return type `size_t` so use that type for variables.
3. You have a typo in your code into `main`: `myfunc` should be `myFunc`

Answer (score 1):

The function can't magically know, so it's usually solved something along this:

```
void myFunc(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        array[i] = i;
}

#define ARRSZ(arr) arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

    myFunc( ARRSZ(array) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `#define ARRSZ(arr) arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)` and not `#define ARRSZ(arr) sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)`

Comment: `sizeof` returns `size_t` not `int`

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Because it substitutes the whole call parameters to `myFunc`. Weird at least.

Comment: @sp2danny, OK got it, but it's really weird.